# How to determine if a file is identical to one in git's history

Tags: git

I have arbitrary file `foo`, not committed to git.

I also have a file whose entire history has been kept in git, `bar`.

How can I determine if `foo` is identical to any version of `bar` that has ever existed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to tell if the contents of file `foo` appear somewhere in the repo:

```
file=foo  # or argument to script, etc
sha1=$(git hash-object -t blob $file)
repotype=$(git cat-file -t $sha1 2>/dev/null) || {
    echo "file \"$file\" is not in the repo"
    exit 1
}
[ $repotype = blob ] || {
    echo "uh oh: file \"$file\" matches non-file ($repotype) object"
    exit 1
}
```

However, just because `foo` appears in the repo as a blob, does not mean it appears under the name `bar` (or maybe not even at all, it could have been `git add`ed but never checked in under a commit).  So now look at every (reasonable?) commit, extracting the blob-ID for your target path, skipping the commit if it's not in there:

```
target_path=bar

git rev-list --branches |     # or --all, or HEAD, or (etc)
while read id; do
    file_id=$(git rev-parse -q --verify $id:$target_path) || continue
    [ $file_id = $sha1 ] || continue
    echo "found \"$file\" as \"$target_path\" in $id"
    # do more here if you like, e.g., git show $id
done
```

If you want to find it under *any* name, rather than some particular explicit name, you can `git ls-tree -r` each commit to find all `blob`s and check their IDs.

(note: untested except piecemeal, and an occasional bit may have been retyped or altered along the way, beware of typos or silly errors)

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of `md5sum`, `git log` and `grep` would work:

```
for SHA in `git log --pretty=format:"%h" bar`; do 
  git show $SHA:bar | md5sum
done | grep `md5sum foo| cut -d' ' -f1`
```

The above command `git log --pretty=format:"%h" bar` get the list of all commits for `bar` file then we do md5sum on each one of them (`git show` to show the file in that commit). At the end we grep the md5sum of `foo` file